# Processes if call requests.get()

Tags: python, python-requests

while working with python Requests, I met the problem with `ConnectionRefusedError [WinError 10061]`, because of network settings and limitations in my network, or company's network software won't allow it (I think).

But I was interested in what happens when I call `requests.get()`. Maybe I'm not good at reading the documentation, but I could not find any processes which happen after the call.
For example, why if I access URL by the browser it is ok, but while I try to access by requests - it fails.

What I'm asking about is what processes happen after the call get() method: starts the server at localhost? configure it? form headers? how it send the request?

Comment: No, none of these. Why would requests.get have anything to do with any of that? Why would it have any processes that happen after the call? It just makes an HTTP request to the URL you give it.

Comment: If you can reach the internet via a browser but not from a python script, you are probably behind a proxy. You'll have to configure your proxy settings for python, if you are allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, most companies use proxy server for each outgoing request. Once set in connection settings, the browsers will read them and set with each request. You can check if proxy is enabled by checking the settings in your browser.

However, when you're making a python request, you will need to set the proxy in the request, like this:

```
    proxyDict = { 
                  "http"  : "192.168.100.3:8080", 
                  "https" : "Some/Same proxy for https", 
                  "ftp"   : "Some proxy for ftp (Optional)"
                }

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict)
```

Also, browsers set the content-types, request headers and other such parameters. You can check browser's developer console, like one of Google Chrome, **and goto Network tab and see what all params are being set with the request, and imply the same paramters in your request.get().** In case of headers, it should be :

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict, headers = {'Content-type':'application/json')
```